# Binary Watch Leetcode

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking

I am trying to solve [Binary Watch](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-watch/) problem in LeetCode using Backtracking.

My code is below (not working)

```
public static void binaryWatchHelper(List<Integer>hours, List<Integer> mins, 
            int num , List<String> possibleTimes,int hoursSum,int minsSum) { 

        //System.out.println( num + " - " + hours + " - " + mins );

        if(num==0) {
            String m = minsSum <10?("0"+minsSum):""+minsSum; 
            possibleTimes.add(hoursSum +":"+m);
        }
        else {
            for(int i=0;i<(hours.size()+mins.size());i++) {

                if(i<hours.size()) {                        
                    int hr =hours.remove(i);
                    hoursSum+=hr;

                    if(hoursSum<=11)
                        binaryWatchHelper(hours, mins, num-1, possibleTimes, hoursSum, minsSum);

                    hours.add(i,hr);
                    hoursSum-=hr;

                } else {

                    int mi =mins.remove(i-hours.size());
                    minsSum+=mi;

                    if(minsSum<=59)
                        binaryWatchHelper(hours, mins, num-1, possibleTimes, hoursSum, minsSum);

                    mins.add(i-hours.size(),mi);
                    minsSum-=mi;                
                }
            }
        }       
    }
```

I found the below code(C++) in the leetcode discussion page and it is working fine.

```
void helper(vector<string>& res, pair<int, int> time, int num, int start_point) {
        if (num == 0) {
            res.push_back(to_string(time.first) +  (time.second < 10 ?  ":0" : ":") + to_string(time.second));
            return;
        }
        for (int i = start_point; i < hour.size() + minute.size(); i ++)
            if (i < hour.size()) {    
                time.first += hour[i];
                if (time.first < 12)     helper(res, time, num - 1, i + 1);     // "hour" should be less than 12.
                time.first -= hour[i];
            } else {     
                time.second += minute[i - hour.size()];
                if (time.second < 60)    helper(res, time, num - 1, i + 1);     // "minute" should be less than 60.
                time.second -= minute[i - hour.size()];
            }
    }
```

The above c++ algo is very similar to what i have written. But my code is not working. Can anyone explain me what am i missing?

Instead of passing the startIndex, I am removing the element. But why my code is not working?

I tried printing the stack-trace of calls and of-course both are very different. Can anyone point me out what am i missing?

I am getting incorrect output.

My code Output for n=2

```
[3:00, 5:00, 9:00, 1:01, 1:02, 1:04, 1:08, 1:16, 1:32, 3:00, 6:00, 10:00, 2:01, 2:02, 2:04, 2:08, 2:16, 2:32, 5:00, 6:00, 4:01, 4:02, 4:04, 4:08, 4:16, 4:32, 9:00, 10:00, 8:01, 8:02, 8:04, 8:08, 8:16, 8:32, 1:01, 2:01, 4:01, 8:01, 0:03, 0:05, 0:09, 0:17, 0:33, 1:02, 2:02, 4:02, 8:02, 0:03, 0:06, 0:10, 0:18, 0:34, 1:04, 2:04, 4:04, 8:04, 0:05, 0:06, 0:12, 0:20, 0:36, 1:08, 2:08, 4:08, 8:08, 0:09, 0:10, 0:12, 0:24, 0:40, 1:16, 2:16, 4:16, 8:16, 0:17, 0:18, 0:20, 0:24, 0:48, 1:32, 2:32, 4:32, 8:32, 0:33, 0:34, 0:36, 0:40, 0:48]
```

C++ code output :

```
[3:00, 5:00, 9:00, 1:01, 1:02, 1:04, 1:08, 1:16, 1:32, 6:00, 10:00, 2:01, 2:02, 2:04, 2:08, 2:16, 2:32, 4:01, 4:02, 4:04, 4:08, 4:16, 4:32, 8:01, 8:02, 8:04, 8:08, 8:16, 8:32, 0:03, 0:05, 0:09, 0:17, 0:33, 0:06, 0:10, 0:18, 0:34, 0:12, 0:20, 0:36, 0:24, 0:40, 0:48]
```

My call trace for num =2

```
2 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  1 - [2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 4] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 4, 8] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 4, 8] - [1, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
  1 - [1, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 4] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 4, 8] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 4, 8] - [1, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
  1 - [1, 2, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 8] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 8] - [1, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 8] - [1, 2, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
  1 - [1, 2, 4] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 4] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 4] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4] - [1, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4] - [1, 2, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4] - [1, 2, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
  1 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 4, 8] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 4, 8] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 8] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [2, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [2, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [2, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [2, 4, 8, 16]
  1 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 4, 8] - [1, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 4, 8] - [1, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 8] - [1, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4] - [1, 4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [4, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 4, 8, 16]
  1 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 8] - [1, 2, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4] - [1, 2, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [2, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 8, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 8, 16]
  1 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4] - [1, 2, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [2, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 4, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 16, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 16]
  1 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [2, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 4, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 8, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 32]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8]
  1 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
    0 - [2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
    0 - [1, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
    0 - [1, 2, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
    0 - [1, 2, 4] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [2, 4, 8, 16]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 4, 8, 16]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 8, 16]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 16]
    0 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8]
```

C++ Code Call trace:

```
2 - [1, 2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  1 - [2, 4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [16, 32]
  0 - [] - [32]
  0 - [] - []
  1 - [4, 8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [16, 32]
  0 - [] - [32]
  0 - [] - []
  1 - [8] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [16, 32]
  0 - [] - [32]
  0 - [] - []
  1 - [] - [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [16, 32]
  0 - [] - [32]
  0 - [] - []
  1 - [] - [2, 4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [16, 32]
  0 - [] - [32]
  0 - [] - []
  1 - [] - [4, 8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [16, 32]
  0 - [] - [32]
  0 - [] - []
  1 - [] - [8, 16, 32]
  0 - [] - [16, 32]
  0 - [] - [32]
  0 - [] - []
  1 - [] - [16, 32]
  0 - [] - [32]
  0 - [] - []
  1 - [] - [32]
  0 - [] - []
  1 - [] - []
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add more information in the question about what's not working in your code? There are only 11 possible inputs, so one of those must be wrong. Does your code miss out some possible times for one particular output? Does it crash? Something else?

Comment: Hey Paul , added sample output and call trace.

Comment: I think `calling by value and reference`  in java make this problems. Check this https://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html

Answer (score 1):

The backtracking approach to solving this problem is redundant. You can solve this problem using some bit manipulation technique.

***Point to observe***

**The total number of set bits used to denote hour and to denote minute should be equal to the passed argument `n`.**

You have then `0 - 11` hours and `0 - 59` minutes. Using two for loops and only selecting the hour `h` and minute `m` for which the sum of set bits is equal to `n` you can make your solution much more elegant and faster. The goal of the problem is also to test your bit manipulation skills.

```
    public List<String> readBinaryWatch(int n) {
        List<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int h = 0; h < 12; h++) {
            for(int m = 0; m < 60; m++) {
                if(Integer.bitCount(h) + Integer.bitCount(m) == n) { // Checking whether the current h and m combination is a valid result. 
                   //If the sum of their set bits is equal to n then the combination is a valid result and add that combination to result
                    ret.add(String.format("%d:%02d",h,m));
                }
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the answer above, I solved this problem this way too.

I also have a bit different solution. You can find it here
https://github.com/yan-khonski-it/leetcode/tree/master/src/main/java/com/yk/leetcode/binary_watch

The idea is that you can have calculated hours combinations for each hours leds. For example, 0 leds mean 0 hours, 1 led mean any option from 1, 2, 4, 8.
More details
https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-watch/discuss/601642/C%2B%2B-straight-solution-with-tables-of-hours-and-minutes

Same applies to minutes. One minutes led means any option from 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 minutes.

Now you have `nLeds` the number of leds on the watch. `nLeds = hoursLeds + minutesLeds`. In this case, you will have all possible hours combinations and minutes combinations, and you just join them.

Now,from [the link above](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-watch/discuss/601642/C%2B%2B-straight-solution-with-tables-of-hours-and-minutes), you can find tables with defined values. You can hard-code these tables or you can build them your self.

```
// Hours combinations depending on leds number
    private static final int[] hours0 = calculateLedsNumbers(0, 12);
    private static final int[] hours1 = calculateLedsNumbers(1, 12);
    private static final int[] hours2 = calculateLedsNumbers(2, 12);
    private static final int[] hours3 = calculateLedsNumbers(3, 12);
    private static final int[] hours4 = calculateLedsNumbers(4, 12);

    // Minutes combinations depending on leds number
    private static final int[] minutes0 = calculateLedsNumbers(0, 60);
    private static final int[] minutes1 = calculateLedsNumbers(1, 60);
    private static final int[] minutes2 = calculateLedsNumbers(2, 60);
    private static final int[] minutes3 = calculateLedsNumbers(3, 60);
    private static final int[] minutes4 = calculateLedsNumbers(4, 60);
    private static final int[] minutes5 = calculateLedsNumbers(5, 60);
    private static final int[] minutes6 = calculateLedsNumbers(6, 60);
```

And then you loop through all possible combinations of hours and minutes and combine them.

```
final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(191);
    for (int hoursLeds = 0; hoursLeds < 4; hoursLeds++) {
        int[] possibleHours = getHoursFromLed(hoursLeds);
        for (int minutesLeds = 0; minutesLeds < 6; minutesLeds++) {
            if (hoursLeds + minutesLeds > nLeds) {
                break;
            }

            if (hoursLeds + minutesLeds == nLeds) {
                int [] possibleMinutes = getMinutesFromLed(minutesLeds);
                combineHoursAndMinutes(possibleHours, possibleMinutes, result);
            }
        }
    }
```

and combine

```
private static void combineHoursAndMinutes(int[] possibleHours, int[] possibleMinutes, List<String> result) {
    for (int possibleHour : possibleHours) {
        for (int possibleMinute : possibleMinutes) {
              // Same as String.format("%d:%02d", possibleHour, possibleMinute), but faster.
            result.add(hoursFormatted[possibleHour] + minutesFormatted[possibleMinute]);
        }
    }
}
```

By the way, this is the result
[image]